# How to find the height of the deepest full level in a binary search tree?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

For example, given the tree:

```
                                    10
               5                                15
       0             6                    12                    20   // full
-5        2              8                   14          16           22
             4                                              18             24
                                                                              26
```

The value returned by the function `highestFull(BinaryNodeX<Comparable> *t)` would be 3 as the height of the deepest full level is three.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a node has no left or right node, you know that the deepest full level is 1 - the node itself.

If it has left and right nodes, recurse and choose the smaller.

```
highestFull(BinaryNodeX<Comparable> *t)
{
   if ( ! t->left || ! t->right ) return 1;
   return 1 + std::min( highestFull(t->left), highestFull(t->right) );
}
```

Comment: But what about siblings?

Comment: @DonRoby this solution doesn't require any node to be aware of its sibling.  The parent node would instead determine the "fullness" of the sibling children.

Comment: I've read more carefully now, and you're right.  +1!